# PHP memcache client - does it depend on the servers IP addresses to route?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, memcached

I'm migrating from a single memcache server to multiple on AWS.
I need to access the memcache servers from the internal network and from the outside. so I'm using

```
// get data from memcache for counter
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->addServer('server1_internal_IP', 11211);
$memcache->addServer('server2_internal_IP', 11211);
```

From an app server on another zone I'm accessing the same servers using:

```
$memcache->addServer('server1_external_IP', 11211);
$memcache->addServer('server2_external_IP', 11211);
```

When the local server writes to memcache and the remote one reads, It looks like the routing doesnt go to the same servers

Could it be because I'm using different IP addresses (amazon internal and external) to access the servers? So the routing mechanism takes the actual IP addresses into account when doing the routing? I thought it was supposed to be a simple CRC32 on the keys

Answer (score 1):

Found out that when memcache.hash_strategy=consistent the IP addresses are used in the hashing algorithm so you cant route to the same servers with different addresses (which is the case in AWS internal and external IP addresses for each server).

The solution is  to switch to standard hashing. Add this in php.ini:

[memcached]
memcache.hash_strategy=standard

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really ideal. if possible you should segregate your data into separate memcache servers based on what you are storing.

If you use the built in hashing algorithms to spread your data across servers you can't guarantee that load will spread evenly and adding/removing servers will reset your entire cache across all the servers which will cause major problems on your site (everyone gets logged out/ looses their cart contents if you use it to store sessions)